# t-sql transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some issues creating a query where I kind of transpose the rows as columns.
For example, I have following table:

```
UniqueId                               | PropertyName   | PropertyValue  | Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EA91B396-A3DE-4A16-850B-30D7CD45D753   | FileName       | Test.txt       | 2014-09-26 19:12:58.203
EA91B396-A3DE-4A16-850B-30D7CD45D753   | SourceLocation | C:\Temp        | 2014-09-26 19:12:58.203
1036E17B-3527-4F26-9ABD-565DF98C7A98   | FileName       | Test2.txt      | 2014-09-26 19:15:02.215
1036E17B-3527-4F26-9ABD-565DF98C7A98   | SourceLocation | C:\Temp2       | 2014-09-26 19:15:02.215
```

Now I would like to transpose this data into the following table:

```
UniqueId                               | FileName       | SourceLocation  | Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EA91B396-A3DE-4A16-850B-30D7CD45D753   | Test.txt       | C:\Temp         | 2014-09-26 19:12:58.203
1036E17B-3527-4F26-9ABD-565DF98C7A98   | Test2.txt      | C:\Temp2        | 2014-09-26 19:15:02.215
```

So basically each value of "PropertyName" becomes a column in my output query and the "PropertyValue" column becomes the value of that new column.
Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google:  "sql server pivot".  If you don't know the list of all the properties, through "dynamic" in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name T 
            PIVOT (
                   MAX(PropertyValue)
                   FOR PropertyName
                   IN ([FileName],[SourceLocation])
                   )p
```

### Result

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
║               UniqueId               ║          Time           ║ FileName  ║ SourceLocation ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║ EA91B396-A3DE-4A16-850B-30D7CD45D753 ║ 2014-09-26 19:12:58.203 ║ Test.txt  ║ C:\Temp        ║
║ 1036E17B-3527-4F26-9ABD-565DF98C7A98 ║ 2014-09-26 19:15:02.217 ║ Test2.txt ║ C:\Temp2       ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the PropertyName values will be you can use PIVOT and hard code the values:

```
SELECT [UniqueId], [FileName], [SourceLocation], [Time] 
FROM (
    SELECT [UniqueId], [PropertyName], [PropertyValue], [Time] 
    FROM Table1 
    ) SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(PropertyValue) FOR PropertyName IN ([FileName], [SourceLocation])
) AS PivotedTable
```

If the PropertyName values can vary you need to use dynamic SQL to build a list of properties for the PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLS= ISNULL(@COLS + ',','') + QUOTENAME(PropertyName)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PropertyName FROM Table1) AS Properties

SET @SQL =
  N'SELECT [UniqueId], ' + @COLS + ', [Time]
    FROM Table1
    PIVOT (
       MAX(PropertyValue) FOR PropertyName IN (' + @COLS + ')
       ) AS PivotedTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a998/1)

Comment: There are only two values OP is looking for, why would you go through all this trouble just to Pivot 2 values :S

Comment: @M.Ali Guess I didn't read the question well enough to know that there would always be just two values. In any case it won't hurt to show the alternative procedure in my opinion, maybe it might be useful for the OP in the future if more properties are added. Plus I already had the skeleton code, so adapting it wasn't much work ;)

Comment: Thx jpw, good to know the solution for dynamic values as well :) There won't be more than 2 different values, so I opted for the solution of M. Ali.