# T-SQL Rows to column and compute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need a little help converting this:

[image: Source]

to...

[image: Destination]

where

Percentage is simply N / (D - E)

I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084700/t-sql-transpose-rows-to-columns), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) and few other posts.
Is there a simpler way to add compute to the transposed columns !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option

```
Select *
      ,Pct = ( IsNull([N],0)+0.0) / NullIf((IsNull([D],0)-IsNull([E],0) ),0)
 From  YourTable A
 Pivot ( sum(Users) for Marker in ([D],[E],[N]) ) pvt
```

**EDIT - Corrected for NULLS**

Comment: I was feeling a little dumb to ask a SQL question, but thanks a ton for helping me out.

Comment: @WeShall No worries, that's why we are here  :)   Learning is the fun part

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subquery or CTE:

```
select d.*,
       n * 1.0 / nullif(d - e, 0) as ratio
from (select date,
             sum(case when market = 'D' then users else 0 end) as d,
             sum(case when market = 'E' then users else 0 end) as e,
             sum(case when market = 'N' then users else 0 end) as n
      from t
      group by date
     ) d;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I referred to some of your previous answers / comments on the topic. That was helpful too.